# Cant read xml files in a Cocoa app

Tags: xml, cocoa, swift

I am trying to write a mac app which can read and write xml to files on the system.
I'm a beginner to Cocoa (I'm coming from iOS) so this question may be very basic. I've worked out that I have to have a document type app and that I read and write data using 
override func dataOfType(typeName: String, error outError: NSErrorPointer) -> NSData?
and
override func readFromData(data: NSData, ofType typeName: String, error outError: NSErrorPointer) -> Bool {

I believe my problem is with the Document Types or Exported UTI (which are still a black art to me)

If I make the extensions in each anything other than xml (lets say grf) then things work fine. I can read and write xml data to files with the extension .grf

However if I set the extensions to xml then I can write data to an xml file, but when I try to read it, then xml files are disabled in the file navigator. So I can't select them and therefore can't read them.

I don't need help with parsing the xml once I've got it. It's just understanding how I read the xml files.

Comment: Can we presume that you've established an NSURLConnection to the file with its delegate methods?

Comment: I am not trying to read a remote file but one locally. I can do that fine if it has any extension other than xml. The problem is that if I want to read files with an xml extension and set the extension to xml in the Document Type and UTI then when I go to read the file, the file is not available.